# How to use new_direct_message with Net::Twitter::Lite

Tags: perl, twitter

I'm trying to use in a script some DM functionalities and request.
My goal is on an event, sending a DM to a chosen follower.

For now, my working code is like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Net::Twitter::Lite::WithAPIv1_1;

my $twitter = Net::Twitter::Lite::WithAPIv1_1->new(
    access_token_secret => 'XXX',
    consumer_secret     => 'XXX',
    access_token        => 'XXX',
    consumer_key        => 'XXX',
    user_agent          => 'Myself',
    ssl => 1,
);

my $user        = 'myself';
my $message_ack = "Hasta la vista, baby";
print "[sending: '$message_ack' to '$user'\n";

my $ack         = $twitter->new_direct_message($user, $message_ack);
```

I have the following return:

```
# perl test.pl
[sending: 'Hasta la vista, baby' to 'myself'
new_direct_message expected 1 args at test.pl line 21.
```

I don't get is as the CPAN doc states that the 2 parameters given are required:

> new_direct_message(user, text)
>
> Parameters: user, text, screen_name, user_id, include_entities
>
> Required: user, text
>
> Sends a new direct message to the specified user from the
>   authenticating user. Requires both the user and text parameters. 
>   Returns the sent message when successful. In order to support numeric
>   screen names, the screen_name or user_id parameters may be used
>   instead of user.
>
> Returns: DirectMessage

Any hints on this one?

I've tried to google a bit on this, and I've found nothing really helpful. On some examples, they use the exact same thing as me (here for example: http://www.sevagas.com/Real-time-system-alerts-using-Twitter-OAuth-implementation on line 85)

Comment: The documentation seems confused. Only `text` is listed as required, but it also says "Requires both the user and text parameters".

Answer (score 1):

I just figured it out with toolic comment.
So, there's the answer if someone ever have the same mistake :

Don't use

```
$twitter->new_direct_message($user, $message_ack);
```

but

```
$twitter->new_direct_message({ user => $user, text => $message_ack });
```

It looks like you have to pass a hashref, but I couldn't clearly see that hint in the doc.